# custom camera view switch camera front back

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am using custom camera view for my app. but when i am changing my view its not responding well i can't able to see my view whatever changes its stop showing live view if i am not changing then its working just fine ,i don`t know i try alot were i am doing mistake or missing something. my code is

```html
-(void)abdbcam
{
    session=[[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];
    
    /* AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice=[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
     NSError *error;
     AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:&error];
     if([session canAddInput:deviceInput])
     {
     [session addInput:deviceInput];
     
     }*/
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontcamera;
    AVCaptureDevice *backcamera;
    
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        NSLog(@"Device Nmae %@",[device localizedName]);
        
        if ([device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo])
        {
            if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
            {
                NSLog(@"device position: bAck");
                backcamera = device;
            }
            else
            {
                
                NSLog(@"device position : front");
                frontcamera = device;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!FrontCamera)
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backcamera error:&error];
        if (!input)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: trying to open camera: %@", error);
            
        }
        [session addInput:input];
    }
    if (FrontCamera) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontcamera error:&error];
        if (!input) {
            NSLog(@"error: trying to open camera: %@", error);
            
        }
        [session addInput:input];
        
    }
    
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer=[[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:session];
    [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view]layer];
    [rootLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    CGRect frame=self.camerarole.frame;
    
    
    [previewLayer setFrame:frame];
    
    [rootLayer insertSublayer:previewLayer atIndex:0];
    
    stillImageOutput=[[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc]init];
    
    NSDictionary *outputSetting=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSetting];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];
    [session startRunning];
}

// now my segment controller code is

- (IBAction)switchcamera:(id)sender {
    if (cameraswitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        FrontCamera = YES;
        [self abdbcam];
    }
    if (cameraswitch.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [self abdbcam];
    }
```

please have a look and suggest me if i am doing any mistake

Answer (score 0):

So I've already implemented custom camera switch. Check this code below:

`isUsingFrontFacingCamera` is a bool flag, too detect which camera are you using at the moment

```
- (void) switchCam{

    if (![self cameraIsRunning])
        return;

    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;

    if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    else
        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {

            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] beginConfiguration];

            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];

            for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] inputs]) {
                [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
            }

            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] addInput:input];
            [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] commitConfiguration];

            break;
        }
    }

    isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for while i am working. i am posting this because it will be helpful for anyone.

```
NSArray *inputs = session.inputs;
for ( AVCaptureDeviceInput *input in inputs ) {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = input.device;
    if ( [device hasMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
        AVCaptureDevicePosition position = device.position;
        AVCaptureDevice *newCamera = nil;
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *newInput = nil;

        if (position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
            newCamera = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
        else
            newCamera = [self cameraWithPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionFront];
        newInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:newCamera error:nil];

        // beginConfiguration ensures that pending changes are not applied immediately
        [session beginConfiguration];

        [session removeInput:input];
        [session addInput:newInput];

        // Changes take effect once the outermost commitConfiguration is invoked.
        [session commitConfiguration];
        break;
    }
}


- (AVCaptureDevice *)cameraWithPosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition)position
 {
   NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for ( AVCaptureDevice *device in devices )
    if ( device.position == position )
        return device;
    return nil;
 }
```